# regex custom delimiters

Tags: android, regex, text, split, delimiter

I am writing an android app that takes as an input a .txt file about 25 pages. I want to split this text to four parts using custom delimiters. For example let's say I want to split the text in the place where the phrase  is. I have tried using

```
file.split("[<BUILDING rid="1">]")
```

and `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(file, "\\b<BUILDING rid="1">\\b");`

and `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(file, "[<BUILDING rid=\"1\">]");`

and many more but I cannot find a way to create custom delimiters using regex and I split my text in wrong places. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try `file.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter))`.

Comment: It did work. Thanks